# getSelection fails on top commercial websites, how to unblock?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have made my Chrome extension to facilitate web content capture (just copies the content to a database on my server with a simple 'select' + 'click') for further processing, but major commercial websites seem to be blocking the getSelection() function. It only works on my own sites and Wikipedia. How do they block it ? Is it possible to unblock ?

The sample code in popup.js to test this problem is very simple. It is executed when clicking on the extension icon:

```
window.addEventListener("load",init);

function init() {

    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
        function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {method: "getSelection"},
                function(response){
                   chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(response);
               }
            );
        }
    );    
}
```

The listener code is:

```
[niko@dev1 ext]$ cat selection.js 
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection") {
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  }else {
    sendResponse({}); 
  }
});
[niko@dev1 ext]$
```

When I use Wikipedia I get the selection in the console without any problems:

```
Object {data: "nal networks of newspapers. The Democratic party w…rs, Evangelical Protestants, and social reformers"}
```

But when I use some top news website i get nothing:

```
Object {data: ""}
```

How do these sites block getSelection() method?

Comment: Your question doesn't contain critical code (what answers to `getSelection`, how it is injected). As such, it's not answerable in its current form.

Comment: @Xan getSelection is not answered by my code , but by the code of commercial websites. If I would write the answer to it myself I wouldn't ask this question in the first place. My extension uses  sendMessage() to send and the function(response) gets the reply and writes to console the data received, but as you can see, it gets nothing.

Comment: Doesn't look like you understand my question. Where's the listener to `onMessage`? How is it injected?

Comment: @Xan I am using "simple one-time requests" protocol so you just declare a javascript function(response) { yourcode here.... } and that function is executed on incoming message. Note that my code works with all pages that are not heavily commercial. Somehow popular sites are blocking my requests.

Comment: I'm making one last attempt. Your `sendMessage` talks with a content script. You did not include that code, and the code (or manifest entry) that injects the content script. Without them, the question is meaningless - you included the least important part.

Comment: @Xan , sorry, modified the question and included the code you were asking.